# Unable to mock API request

Tags: typescript, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

Having a really hard time setting up [jest-test-mock](https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock) in in my TypeScript project. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction?

I've got a function that looks like this:

**retrieveData.ts**

```js
import fetch from 'cross-fetch'; 

export async function retrieveData({
  endpoint,
  configuration,
  auth
}: dataInterface): Promise<object> {
  try {
    console.log('Fetching the requested data... ')

    const settings = configuration
      ? JSON.parse(render(configuration || '', auth))
      : {}

    if (settings.body) {
      // Ensures the body is stringified in the case of a post request being made.
      settings.body = JSON.stringify(settings.body)
    }

    const response = await fetch(endpoint, settings)
    return await response.json()
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`There was an error fetching from the API: ${error}`)
  }
}
```

And I'm testing it like this in **fetch.test.ts**

```js
// Enable the mocks
import { enableFetchMocks } from 'jest-fetch-mock'
enableFetchMocks()
import fetchMock from 'jest-fetch-mock';

import {retrieveData, generateExport} from '../src/fetch'

describe('fetch', () => {
  describe('retrieveData', () => {
    it('should return some data', async () => {
      fetchMock.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({ data: '12345' }))
      const data = await retrieveData({
        endpoint: 'https://example.com'
      })

      expect(data).toEqual({ data: '12345' })
    })
  })
})
```

The problem I'm having is that this library doesn't seem to take over the call to `fetch`. Putting a fully qualified URL into my function will result in actual data getting returned. I expect it to retrieve the `data: '12345'` object. Where am I going wrong here?

**Update:**

The following pattern works when importing `import 'cross-fetch/polyfill';` but if I use `import fetch from 'cross-fetch';` it does not. The problem with using the first import statement is that it errors my linter saying that `fetch` is not defined. If I console log before the fetch import it shows the correct mock constructor. I've tried playing around with the import order of the mocks but it still has the same problem:

```
import fetchMock, {enableFetchMocks} from 'jest-fetch-mock'
import {retrieveData, generateExport} from '../src/fetch'
enableFetchMocks()
```

It's clearly some sort of import order issue but I'm not sure the right way to solve this with Jest. Is adding a `fetch` to the global object in eslint an appropriate solution for this?

Comment: It's most likely because `cross-fetch` is imported before you mock it, to test if this is the case, try adding console.logs before the creation of the function and before your mocking of cross-fetch

Comment: Console logging `fetch` at the top of `retrieveData` before the import shows the correct constructor. Looking here https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch#install it says to use `import fetch from 'cross-fetch';` but using `import 'cross-fetch/polyfill';` seems to work instead. Confusing...

Comment: Updated the original post with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code, please.

```
describe('retrieveData', () => {
  it('should return some data', () => {
    fetchMock.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({ data: '12345' }))
    retrieveData({
      endpoint: 'https://example.com'
    }).then(res => {
       expect(res).toEqual({ data: '12345' })
    })
  })
})
```